# angular radio how to isolate

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

Here is my issue: I have a quiz that consist of 5 questions. Each question has one question and three answers. I'm using bootstrap radios and angularjs. When I choose one of the answers in two different questions I have only one choosen answer. How to isolate questions?
I take my question from db

index.html :

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="radioForm">
    <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <p>{{question.ask}}</p>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="question.answer1" name="optionsRadios" ng-value="question.answer1">
                {{question.answer1}}
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="question.answer2" name="optionsRadios" ng-value="question.answer2">
                {{question.answer2}}
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="question.answer3" name="optionsRadios" ng-value="question.answer3">
                {{question.answer3}}
            </label>
        </div>

     <br />
     </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Проверить</button>
</form>
```

controller.js :

```
angular.module('testpage').controller('TestpageController', ['$scope', '$http',
function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/list/questions')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.questions = data;
            // console.log(data);

        })
        .error(function(err) {
            console.log("err", err);
        });
}])
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your current code.

Answer (score -1):

Ok! Here it is http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm  . I just need to change names and for each group of answers must be unique name.